# How does self contained installer (on Windows) work?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation

Just out of curiosity, I would like to understand the behaviors of those self contained installer programs and try to write a simple installer myself.

I did some search on Google and did not really find a useful article explaining it. However AFAIK, an installer should have a small chunk of code residing in the top of the executable. It pulls data out from the rear of the executable and interprets them as files according to an inventory file (probably xml?). Other operations such as writing register entries can also be specified in the inventory file.

Now is my guess of the file structure true? If so I think I just need to read about the PE format and then it would be conceptually easy for me to implement it. If my guess is wrong, I would love to know how exactly it works.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally installer packages are self-contained compressed executables (SFX) that contains:

- A small installer executable
- A compressed file structure with files to extract
- Some configuration files (xml, ini, json, properties) to define file destinations, registry entries, desktop/start menu shortcuts, instalation modes
- Extra files (dll, icon/image resources) to make the installer work.

For MSI packages, it's a bit more complex. It's a propietary format packaged as a SQL database in a COM structured storage file. It contains also a virtual file system inside the installation package (file access using file streams).

You can review some free tools and check many typical features to make installer executables like:

- Wix (For MSI installers) http://wixtoolset.org/
- Nullsoft Installer (NSIS) http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page
- Inno Setup http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Looks like my guess is somewhat on track for non-msi installers. And thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows it's pretty much

Declarative: MSI, AppX, ClickOnce

Imperative: any number of third party tools, scripts and home grown EXEs

MSI is typically your best choice.  The runtime is already part of windows so when you double click the MSI database MSIEXEC takes over.  The point of the declarative models is to separate what needs to be done from how you do it.   The imperative models are basically some simple to complex framework to write procedural code to do the actual installation work.

It's far to broad of a question to ask in detail how any of these work at a low level.  For MSI it's all in the Windows Platform SDK documentation on MSDN.